# What are the best exercises for very skinny hands (not arms) that need muscle and fat?

Tags: exercise, hands

Also the answer can't be get fatter because especially in teens the hands tend to not want to grow.

What are the best exercises?

Comment: Exercises for what? weight lifting? Yoga? Pilates?

Comment: I think they're trying to find exercises that will bulk up their hands.

Comment: I'm not really expert enough to answer this, but my suspicion (surprise, surprise) is that a good strength training program will help a lot as you'll be using your grip a lot. I think hand size is a bit permanent though. I know some pretty tough customers with active lifestyles, some with small hands and some with bigger.

Comment: Is that even possible @SeanDuggan ?

Comment: @JustDoIt: Good question. Parts of the palm do have muscle tissue. Trying to increase the fatty deposits runs the same problem as spot reduction / increase anywhere else, namely that it can't be targeted. Scar tissue is probably right out...

Comment: @SeanDuggan is correct, there is some muscle tissue, but it is almost exclusive to the lower palm for the thumb and small finger (Which is why losing the pinky/small finger is so devastating to grip strength). Most of the muscles that control the fingers are in the forearm. About the only way to really increase the size of the fingers is to get fat (Or have a disease state of some sort).

Comment: Is this a question about appearance, or, functional ability?

Comment: It's about hands that are skinny and not only look like they're dyeing of bone/size mass like a skeleton but also of course getting less and less functional. It's about getting your hands bigger & fatter in bone & fat mass, and stronger.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amLBZyADoW0

Answer (score 2):

I suggests grip training (crushing, gripping, pinching ...), forearm training, climbing and hard physical labor. Some scientific researches have found that competitive climbers hands have thicker and denser bones, muscles and tendons. That is due to the body adaptation to externals stimuli. In the same way woodworkers, lumberjacks, smiths and many hard workers develop strong and bigger hands

Comment: The research on **thickening** bones sounds interesting. I'd be grateful if you could source that. I'm particularly interested in the extent to which they can grow in volume.

Comment: This research talks about hands' bones adaptations in climbers : http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2100343/#!po=0.625000 . This one gives a general overview quoting other researches : http://scienceblogs.com/webeasties/2013/01/22/rock-climbing-fat-fingers-and-arthritis/.